# Access Queries comparing two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have two tables in Access, Table A and Table B:

Table MasterLockInsNew:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Value |   Date   |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |   123 | 12/02/13 |
|  2 |  1231 | 11/02/13 |
|  4 |  1265 | 16/02/13 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

Table InitialPolData:

```
+----+-------+----------+---+
| ID | Value |   Date   |Type
+----+-------+----------+---+
|  1 |   123 | 12/02/13 | x |
|  2 |  1231 | 11/02/13 | x |      
|  3 |  1238 | 10/02/13 | y |      
|  4 |  1265 | 16/02/13 | a |      
|  7 |  7649 | 18/02/13 | z |      
+----+-------+----------+---+
```

All I want are the **rows** from table B for IDs not contained in A. My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT Distinct InitialPolData.*
FROM InitialPolData
WHERE InitialPolData.ID NOT IN (SELECT Distinct InitialPolData.ID
                                from InitialPolData INNER JOIN
                                     MasterLockInsNew
                                     ON InitialPolData.ID=MasterLockInsNew.ID);
```

But whenever I run this in Access it crashes!! The tables are fairly large but I don't think this is the reason.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or try a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM InitialPolData b left outer join
MasterLockInsNew a on
b.id = a.id
where
a.id is null
```

Comment: This turned out to be the most easiest way of getting what I wanted. The other answers although looked plausible kept resulting in Access crashing when running the query. Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 2):

Simple subquery will do.

```
select * from InitialPolData 
where id not in (
    select id from MasterLockInsNew
);
```

Comment: Why not a left join? It is often more efficient in Ms Access.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Distinct i.* 
FROM InitialPolData AS i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MasterLockInsNew AS m 
                  WHERE m.ID = i.ID)
```